# Matplotlib - Save image without showing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save thousands of figures which I have annotated with bounding boxes to disk but not display them in jupyter. How can I load the image data into a figure without showing it?

Here is what I have gotten so far:

```
dpi = 150
for index, row in outputs_df.iterrows():
    im = cv2.imread(str(row['path']))
    height, width, channel = im.shape
    figsize = width / float(dpi), height / float(dpi)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ax.axis('off')
    v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TEST[0]), scale=1)
    v = v.overlay_instances(boxes=row['bbox'], assigned_colors=['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'])#draw only bounding box in color
    ax.imshow(v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
    ax.set(xlim=[-0.5, width - 0.5], ylim=[height - 0.5, -0.5], aspect=1)
    fig.savefig(row['dicom_id'] + '_ANNOTATED.jpg', dpi=dpi, transparent=True)
```

Comment: remove `ax.imshow(v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])`?

Comment: @JayMody doesnt work as we never set the image data anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

```py
dpi = 150
for index, row in outputs_df.iterrows():
    im = cv2.imread(str(row['path']))
    height, width, channel = im.shape
    figsize = width / float(dpi), height / float(dpi)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ax.axis('off')
    v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TEST[0]), scale=1)
    v = v.overlay_instances(boxes=row['bbox'], assigned_colors=['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'])#draw only bounding box in color  
    ax.set(xlim=[-0.5, width - 0.5], ylim=[height - 0.5, -0.5], aspect=1)
    fig.savefig(row['dicom_id'] + '_ANNOTATED.jpg', dpi=dpi, transparent=True)
```

Comment: I have tried this before, it only gives a blank figure as we haven't loaded any image data yet